# Does updateCount() and executeUpdate() return samething

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String query="UPDATE table_name SET tab_attr1= ? WHERE tab_attr2= ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1,"test1");
preparedStatement.setString(2,"test2");
//case_1
int count=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

/*
case_2
preparedStatement.execute();
int count=preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
*/
```

Im new to the field and working as a Java Developer

In my testcases both returns the same thing 
    So my question is whether there is any difference between the two
    and if no differences then what is the need for both functions.
    What is the difference between 2 cases..?

Comment: From the `Statement` interface Javadoc, the two methods appear to be fairly similar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: For whatever reason, I have seen `executeUpdate()` being used much more frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

[PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.
>
> **Returns**: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

So basically:

- `executeUpdate()` is used for SQL INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or a DLL statement.
- `execute()` could be used for **any** SQL statement after which you would call `getUpdateCount()`.

Since you're using an UPDATE it doesn't matter in your case. There should be no difference.

Comment: that means getUpdateCount() is exclusively for update queries in execute() statements right

Comment: No, but it would probably only make sense to call getUpdateCount() after some kind of execute statement for update has happened (insert, delete, update etc).

Comment: means getUpdateCount() will work for all 3 data manipulation statements right

Answer (score 3):

executeUpdate(String sql):This method is used for SQL statements which update the database in some way ,returns an int value which represents the number of rows affected by the query

execute(String sql) :This method can be used for all types of SQL statements. If you don’t know which method to use for you SQL statements, then this method can be the best option.
there is also executeQuery(String sql) :This method is used for SQL statements which retrieve some data from the database,This method is meant to be used for select queries which fetch some data from the database