# Will mysql lose data when storing data?

Tags: java, mysql

When I look up some documents, those document authors usually recommend a simple check on mysql data storage operations, such as this:

```java
package org.example.jdbc.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.sql.*;

@SuppressWarnings("JavadocDeclaration")
public class Mysql02Test {
    private static Connection connection;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.24.1/demo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai", "root", "root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void insertTest() throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        int updateCount = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO mysql_jdbc_demo(message) VALUES ('Hello World'), ('Hello World')");
        System.out.println("update: " + update);
        if (updateCount != 2) {
            System.out.println("update != 2");
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to declaring "INSERT IGNORE INTO" in sql to let mysql ignore duplicate data.

Is it possible that `updateCount` is not equal to 2?

The 2 in this example represents the amount of data that needs to be saved.

Comment: sure. if message is a column that doesn't allow duplicates, for instance, and those values are already there. I don't really understand why you have this as unit tests, though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible `executeUpdate` does not return 2. According to the documentation, it returns the amount of affected rows by your SQL DML statement or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing[0]:

> **Returns**:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

There are some pitfalls and quirks depending on the database driver so it's not 100% reliable[1].

[0] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-

[1] [What does it mean when Statement.executeUpdate() returns -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400985/what-does-it-mean-when-statement-executeupdate-returns-1)

Answer (score 0):

According to the post from Diyarbakir, they state from the [Does updateCount() and executeUpdate() return samething](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766426/does-updatecount-and-executeupdate-return-samething) (Stack Overflow)

"From the docs:

executeUpdate()

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

```
Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
```

So basically:

```
executeUpdate() is used for SQL INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or a DLL statement.
execute() could be used for any SQL statement after which you would call getUpdateCount().
```

Since you're using an UPDATE it doesn't matter in your case. There should be no difference" [0]

If this solves your answer, please go back to the original post and give credit to Diyarbakir ([Does updateCount() and executeUpdate() return samething](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766426/does-updatecount-and-executeupdate-return-samething)).

[0] [Does updateCount() and executeUpdate() return samething](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766426/does-updatecount-and-executeupdate-return-samething)